# Check Position During Each Click and Add Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want the class .disabled to be added to the left and/or right controls (.tab-left, .tab-right) if the first or last tab is showing so a user can see that they have reached the end and cannot click any further.

Right now I something like this to prevent the user from going past the end.

```
if (tabs are at the end) {
   return;
 }
```

This works for users not being able to click past the end, but if I add the class before returning, the problem is the .disabled class won't be added until the tabs have reached the end and the user clicks again.

```
if (tabs are at the end) {
   $('.tab-right').addClass('disabled');
   return;
 }
```

I need the disabled class to be added when the last tab is showing, not when the user trys to click past the end.

Here's a link to the js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uue6pgcx/

Comment: So basically you want the class to be added before the javascript returns so the user does not need to click a second time?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option you could try is to enable/disable the right and left buttons once the animation is complete.

```
$ul.filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
    "left": dir + liWidth
  }, {
    complete: function () {
    // Calculate the number of items in the container (without left and right navigation buttons).
    var lisContainer = Math.round(($container.width() - $left.outerWidth() - $right.outerWidth()) / liWidth);
    // Disable right button when list is moved to the left a number of items
    // such as the remaining number of them is less or equal than the number
    // of items that fit in the container.
    $right.toggleClass('disabled', $li.length + $ul.position().left / liWidth <= lisContainer);
    // Disable left button when list is in the origin. 
    $left.toggleClass('disabled', $ul.position().left === 0);
  }
});
```

**Disclaimer**: According to [jQuery outerWidth additional notes](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/), *The number returned by dimensions-related APIs, including .outerWidth(), may be fractional in some cases. Code should not assume it is an integer.*. So lets hope `Math.round` will suffice to get the proper number.
Maybe there is a better way to calculate if the right button must be disabled/enabled instead of relying on the number of items that fit in the container.

Here it is your code with the above modification:
http://jsfiddle.net/0Lsepxeu/